# WPF setting right height for Scrollviewer in a MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, scrollviewer

I'm trying to add a ScrollViewer to a MenuItem that contains a lot of items but it gives me some trouble with the height in the sense that it seems to be fixed and shows only one of the items and part of the scrollbar.

Since the MenuItem is created and then passed to some legacy code that constructs the Menu itself I've suspected that could be some style applied somewhere else but also nulling the Style for all the elements used hasn't worked.

This is a minimal prototype of the code I'm using. Take in account that this works as expected in a separate test project, the only difference is that in the official code I pass the MenuItem to legacy.

```
        var items = new[] {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};

        var newSubMenu = new MenuItem { Header = "New Sub Menu", Style = null };

        var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer
        {
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible,
            Height = 100
        };
        newSubMenu.Items.Add(scrollViewer);

        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var subIt = new MenuItem {Header = item};
            stackPanel.Children.Add(subIt);
        }

        RootMenu.Items.Add(newSubMenu);
```

Comment: Try `newSubMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Header = scrollViewer, Height = 100 });`. But that's a bit of a wild guess, since I don't have access to your legacy code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've tried but it didn't work... it just give me a big MenuItem but the content (scrollviewer, stackpanel and subitems) stay the same, just one item visible.